# Calculate centre of sphere whose surface contains 4 points (C#)

Tags: c#, math

I am using a 3D Voronoi library called MIConvexHull, which calculates a 3D Voronoi diagram for a series of points in 3D space.  However, it does not provide high-level information about the structure of the Voronoi diagram; the reported edges are simply a list of coordinate pairs which then have to have the circumcentre calculated.

Now the library provides an implementation of the circumcentre calculation for a series of 2D points.  As you can see here, the coordinate pairs for the start (orange) and end (green) are shown:

[image: Edge coordinate pairs]

You can visually see that if you take the vertexes listed in each of the edges and you make a circle such that the circumference of that circle touches all of the edges, the centre is where the edge starts.

The *problem* that I have is that my points are 3D and thus it won't be the centre of a circle that's returned, but the centre of a *sphere*.  Unfortunately, advanced mathematics is not something that my head can really handle that well, so I have no idea how to approach this problem.

**How, given 4 points in 3D space, can I get the centre of a sphere such that all of the points lie on the surface of the sphere?**

*EDIT:* In 3D, there will be 4 points provided, not 3.

Comment: Most likely, you want a sphere given _four_ points on its surface.

Comment: In 3D, "triangulation" is actually _tethrahedration_ (even though this isn't a standard term for this).

Comment: Updated; in 3D space the library will provide 4 vertexes for the start and end of each edge.

Comment: Assuming the four points are not coplanar?

Comment: No, the four points will never be coplanar because that a) result in a cell volume of 0 and b) it's impossible to calculate a Voronoi in the first place on that kind of input.

Comment: If the four points are concircular (or collinear), there's still an infinite number of spheres (or planes) that pass through them.

Comment: you need an extra angle or side on the triangle to calculate it with trigonometry. if you can get the radius of the sphere or the adjacent angle, then here is a guide for 2D: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95869/finding-center-of-circle, it's not too hard to do the same thing in 3D.

Comment: Not so helpful, but you need to solve simultaneous equations, 4 of them, in the form `x^2+y^2+z^2=r`.  You likely knew that I guess..

Comment: You could intersect three planes, but there's a closed form for the points as well. Hold on.

Comment: @KierenJohnstone Note that comparing two equations of yours always leads to a linear equation, the plane that bisects the connecting line segment of the two points.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak There's only going to be one sphere where all four points are on the surface of the sphere.  I can't visualise any other spheres that would fit such a list of points.

Comment: If all four points are concircular, then all spheres that respect their common circle contain all four points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a Javascript implementation:

http://www.convertalot.com/sphere_solver.html

And some mathematical explanations:

http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/geometry/sphere4pts.html

> The equation of the sphere ... is given by setting the following determinant to zero:
>
> ```
> | x^2  + y^2  + z^2   x   y   z   1 |
> | x1^2 + y1^2 + z1^2  x1  y1  z1  1 |
> | x2^2 + y2^2 + z2^2  x2  y2  z2  1 | = 0.
> | x3^2 + y3^2 + z3^2  x3  y3  z3  1 |
> | x4^2 + y4^2 + z4^2  x4  y4  z4  1 |
> ```

Comment: You should cite the interesting parts in case the link goes dead.

Comment: That looks exactly like an implementation of what I need.

Answer (score 4):

I converted the Javascript implementation that was linked above into C#.  Here it is:

```
/// <summary>
/// Given four points in 3D space, solves for a sphere such that all four points
/// lie on the sphere's surface.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Translated from Javascript on http://www.convertalot.com/sphere_solver.html, originally
/// linked to by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600739/calculate-centre-of-sphere-whose-surface-contains-4-points-c.
/// </remarks>
public class CircumcentreSolver
{
    private const float ZERO = 0;
    private double m_X0, m_Y0, m_Z0;
    private double m_Radius;
    private double[,] P = 
            {
                { ZERO, ZERO, ZERO },
                { ZERO, ZERO, ZERO },
                { ZERO, ZERO, ZERO },
                { ZERO, ZERO, ZERO }
            };

    /// <summary>
    /// The centre of the resulting sphere.
    /// </summary>
    public double[] Centre
    {
        get { return new double[] { this.m_X0, this.m_Y0, this.m_Z0 }; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The radius of the resulting sphere.
    /// </summary>
    public double Radius
    {
        get { return this.m_Radius; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Whether the result was a valid sphere.
    /// </summary>
    public bool Valid
    {
        get { return this.m_Radius != 0; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Computes the centre of a sphere such that all four specified points in
    /// 3D space lie on the sphere's surface.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a">The first point (array of 3 doubles for X, Y, Z).</param>
    /// <param name="b">The second point (array of 3 doubles for X, Y, Z).</param>
    /// <param name="c">The third point (array of 3 doubles for X, Y, Z).</param>
    /// <param name="d">The fourth point (array of 3 doubles for X, Y, Z).</param>
    public CircumcentreSolver(double[] a, double[] b, double[] c, double[] d)
    {
        this.Compute(a, b, c, d);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Evaluate the determinant.
    /// </summary>
    private void Compute(double[] a, double[] b, double[] c, double[] d)
    {
        P[0, 0] = a[0];
        P[0, 1] = a[1];
        P[0, 2] = a[2];
        P[1, 0] = b[0];
        P[1, 1] = b[1];
        P[1, 2] = b[2];
        P[2, 0] = c[0];
        P[2, 1] = c[1];
        P[2, 2] = c[2];
        P[3, 0] = d[0];
        P[3, 1] = d[1];
        P[3, 2] = d[2];

        // Compute result sphere.
        this.Sphere();
    }

    private void Sphere()
    {
        double r, m11, m12, m13, m14, m15;
        double[,] a =
                {
                    { ZERO, ZERO, ZERO, ZERO },
                    { ZERO, ZERO, ZERO, ZERO },
                    { ZERO, ZERO, ZERO, ZERO },
                    { ZERO, ZERO, ZERO, ZERO }
                };

        // Find minor 1, 1.
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            a[i, 0] = P[i, 0];
            a[i, 1] = P[i, 1];
            a[i, 2] = P[i, 2];
            a[i, 3] = 1;
        }
        m11 = this.Determinant(a, 4);

        // Find minor 1, 2.
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            a[i, 0] = P[i, 0] * P[i, 0] + P[i, 1] * P[i, 1] + P[i, 2] * P[i, 2];
            a[i, 1] = P[i, 1];
            a[i, 2] = P[i, 2];
            a[i, 3] = 1;
        }
        m12 = this.Determinant(a, 4);

        // Find minor 1, 3.
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            a[i, 0] = P[i, 0] * P[i, 0] + P[i, 1] * P[i, 1] + P[i, 2] * P[i, 2];
            a[i, 1] = P[i, 0];
            a[i, 2] = P[i, 2];
            a[i, 3] = 1;
        }
        m13 = this.Determinant(a, 4);

        // Find minor 1, 4.
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            a[i, 0] = P[i, 0] * P[i, 0] + P[i, 1] * P[i, 1] + P[i, 2] * P[i, 2];
            a[i, 1] = P[i, 0];
            a[i, 2] = P[i, 1];
            a[i, 3] = 1;
        }
        m14 = this.Determinant(a, 4);

        // Find minor 1, 5.
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            a[i, 0] = P[i, 0] * P[i, 0] + P[i, 1] * P[i, 1] + P[i, 2] * P[i, 2];
            a[i, 1] = P[i, 0];
            a[i, 2] = P[i, 1];
            a[i, 3] = P[i, 2];
        }
        m15 = this.Determinant(a, 4);

        // Calculate result.
        if (m11 == 0)
        {
            this.m_X0 = 0;
            this.m_Y0 = 0;
            this.m_Z0 = 0;
            this.m_Radius = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            this.m_X0 = 0.5 * m12 / m11;
            this.m_Y0 = -0.5 * m13 / m11;
            this.m_Z0 = 0.5 * m14 / m11;
            this.m_Radius = System.Math.Sqrt(this.m_X0 * this.m_X0 + this.m_Y0 * this.m_Y0 + this.m_Z0 * this.m_Z0 - m15 / m11);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Recursive definition of determinate using expansion by minors.
    /// </summary>
    private double Determinant(double[,] a, int n)
    {
        int i, j, j1, j2;
        double d = 0;
        double[,] m = 
                {
                    { ZERO, ZERO, ZERO, ZERO },
                    { ZERO, ZERO, ZERO, ZERO },
                    { ZERO, ZERO, ZERO, ZERO },
                    { ZERO, ZERO, ZERO, ZERO }
                };

        if (n == 2)
        {
            // Terminate recursion.
            d = a[0, 0] * a[1, 1] - a[1, 0] * a[0, 1];
        }
        else
        {
            d = 0;
            for (j1 = 0; j1 < n; j1++) // Do each column.
            {
                for (i = 1; i < n; i++) // Create minor.
                {
                    j2 = 0;
                    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    {
                        if (j == j1) continue;
                        m[i - 1, j2] = a[i, j];
                        j2++;
                    }
                }

                // Sum (+/-)cofactor * minor.
                d = d + System.Math.Pow(-1.0, j1) * a[0, j1] * this.Determinant(m, n - 1);
            }
        }

        return d;
    }
}
```