# How to calculate the sphere center with 4 points?

Tags: c#, class, math, determinants

The thing is that i am very new on this of programming and now i need to make a program which calculate the center of many spheres(maximum 36, minimum 3), each sphere has 4 points X,Y,Z. be cause my program read a TXT file with the points data i storage it in a List, with an structure like this

```
bolas[n].xyz[row,element]
```

this means that my first set of points for the sphere 1 is like this:

```
bolas[0] = 
 row0.  -> [0] [1] [2]
 row1.  -> [0] [1] [2]
 row2.  -> [0] [1] [2]
 row3.  -> [0] [1] [2]
```

so if i want to use the value of X from my row 1 in the sphere one i have to do this:

```
bolas[0].xyz[0,0]
```

serching on the web i found some one who transform a java code and implement it for c# to calculate the center of the sphere, he created one Class but i am very new and i have no idea how to use the elements on his class, how should i introduce my data into his class and how do i get the result; here is the class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Given four points in 3D space, solves for a sphere such that all four points
/// lie on the sphere's surface.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Translated from Javascript on http://www.convertalot.com/sphere_solver.html, originally
/// linked to by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600739/calculate-centre-of-sphere-whose-surface-contains-4-points-c.
/// </remarks>
public class CircumcentreSolver
{
    private const float ZERO = 0;
    private double m_X0, m_Y0, m_Z0;
    private double m_Radius;
    private double[,] P = 
            {
                { ZERO, ZERO, ZERO },
                { ZERO, ZERO, ZERO },
                { ZERO, ZERO, ZERO },
                { ZERO, ZERO, ZERO }
            };

    /// <summary>
    /// The centre of the resulting sphere.
    /// </summary>
    public double[] Centre
    {
        get { return new double[] { this.m_X0, this.m_Y0, this.m_Z0 }; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The radius of the resulting sphere.
    /// </summary>
    public double Radius
    {
        get { return this.m_Radius; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Whether the result was a valid sphere.
    /// </summary>
    public bool Valid
    {
        get { return this.m_Radius != 0; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Computes the centre of a sphere such that all four specified points in
    /// 3D space lie on the sphere's surface.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a">The first point (array of 3 doubles for X, Y, Z).</param>
    /// <param name="b">The second point (array of 3 doubles for X, Y, Z).</param>
    /// <param name="c">The third point (array of 3 doubles for X, Y, Z).</param>
    /// <param name="d">The fourth point (array of 3 doubles for X, Y, Z).</param>
    public CircumcentreSolver(double[] a, double[] b, double[] c, double[] d)
    {
        this.Compute(a, b, c, d);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Evaluate the determinant.
    /// </summary>
    private void Compute(double[] a, double[] b, double[] c, double[] d)
    {
        P[0, 0] = a[0];
        P[0, 1] = a[1];
        P[0, 2] = a[2];
        P[1, 0] = b[0];
        P[1, 1] = b[1];
        P[1, 2] = b[2];
        P[2, 0] = c[0];
        P[2, 1] = c[1];
        P[2, 2] = c[2];
        P[3, 0] = d[0];
        P[3, 1] = d[1];
        P[3, 2] = d[2];

        // Compute result sphere.
        this.Sphere();
    }

    private void Sphere()
    {
        double r, m11, m12, m13, m14, m15;
        double[,] a =
                {
                    { ZERO, ZERO, ZERO, ZERO },
                    { ZERO, ZERO, ZERO, ZERO },
                    { ZERO, ZERO, ZERO, ZERO },
                    { ZERO, ZERO, ZERO, ZERO }
                };

        // Find minor 1, 1.
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            a[i, 0] = P[i, 0];
            a[i, 1] = P[i, 1];
            a[i, 2] = P[i, 2];
            a[i, 3] = 1;
        }
        m11 = this.Determinant(a, 4);

        // Find minor 1, 2.
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            a[i, 0] = P[i, 0] * P[i, 0] + P[i, 1] * P[i, 1] + P[i, 2] * P[i, 2];
            a[i, 1] = P[i, 1];
            a[i, 2] = P[i, 2];
            a[i, 3] = 1;
        }
        m12 = this.Determinant(a, 4);

        // Find minor 1, 3.
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            a[i, 0] = P[i, 0] * P[i, 0] + P[i, 1] * P[i, 1] + P[i, 2] * P[i, 2];
            a[i, 1] = P[i, 0];
            a[i, 2] = P[i, 2];
            a[i, 3] = 1;
        }
        m13 = this.Determinant(a, 4);

        // Find minor 1, 4.
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            a[i, 0] = P[i, 0] * P[i, 0] + P[i, 1] * P[i, 1] + P[i, 2] * P[i, 2];
            a[i, 1] = P[i, 0];
            a[i, 2] = P[i, 1];
            a[i, 3] = 1;
        }
        m14 = this.Determinant(a, 4);

        // Find minor 1, 5.
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            a[i, 0] = P[i, 0] * P[i, 0] + P[i, 1] * P[i, 1] + P[i, 2] * P[i, 2];
            a[i, 1] = P[i, 0];
            a[i, 2] = P[i, 1];
            a[i, 3] = P[i, 2];
        }
        m15 = this.Determinant(a, 4);

        // Calculate result.
        if (m11 == 0)
        {
            this.m_X0 = 0;
            this.m_Y0 = 0;
            this.m_Z0 = 0;
            this.m_Radius = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            this.m_X0 = 0.5 * m12 / m11;
            this.m_Y0 = -0.5 * m13 / m11;
            this.m_Z0 = 0.5 * m14 / m11;
            this.m_Radius = System.Math.Sqrt(this.m_X0 * this.m_X0 + this.m_Y0 * this.m_Y0 + this.m_Z0 * this.m_Z0 - m15 / m11);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Recursive definition of determinate using expansion by minors.
    /// </summary>
    private double Determinant(double[,] a, double n)
    {
        int i, j, j1, j2;
        double d = 0;
        double[,] m = 
                {
                    { ZERO, ZERO, ZERO, ZERO },
                    { ZERO, ZERO, ZERO, ZERO },
                    { ZERO, ZERO, ZERO, ZERO },
                    { ZERO, ZERO, ZERO, ZERO }
                };

        if (n == 2)
        {
            // Terminate recursion.
            d = a[0, 0] * a[1, 1] - a[1, 0] * a[0, 1];
        }
        else
        {
            d = 0;
            for (j1 = 0; j1 < n; j1++) // Do each column.
            {
                for (i = 1; i < n; i++) // Create minor.
                {
                    j2 = 0;
                    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    {
                        if (j == j1) continue;
                        m[i - 1, j2] = a[i, j];
                        j2++;
                    }
                }

                // Sum (+/-)cofactor * minor.
                d = d + System.Math.Pow(-1.0, j1) * a[0, j1] * this.Determinant(m, n - 1);
            }
        }

        return d;
    }
}
```

How i said my data sphere numbers may variate, but i have a maximum of 36 spheres each one with 4 points x,y,z.
It will be very useful if i could storage the resultant centers in another List, maybe something like:

```
ballCent[0]=
center-> [0][1][2] //center of the sphere[x][y][z].
radius-> [0]       //radius of the sphere.
```

i hope i explain it clear enough,i am not an English native speaker, i really appreciate the help of the community. 
PS. i personally tried the java version of the program with my data and it works just perfect for me. 
here is the link:
http://www.convertalot.com/sphere_solver.html

Comment: This isn't a trivial task. You basically have to resolve a non linear system with 4 variables and 4 equations. You'll need to research how to solve that problem first.

Comment: Finding code in the Internet and simply trying to make it work without trying to understand it is most definitely not the way to go.

Comment: Forget coding, how would you solve this by hand? If you don't know how to do it manually then how do you pretend to program a working algorithm? Once you know how to manually do it then you can start thinking how you'd program it and what tools you'd need. Nobody is going to do your work for you here.

Comment: @InBetween you got it wrong, i do know how to solve it by hand, i do know how it works, my real problem is the coding, as i said i am really new with the coding and don't know how to program the algorithm, conveniently i found the code which i show there, which i have tested in java, but some body make the implementation on c#, my question is how this things work? i mean is it a class just as a function? there are some argument get in the code body as an input and then it returns me the calculation, i am guessing, but i don't really know how... just need an explanation. thanks .

Comment: Good, then your problem is that you are barely learning how to code. Maybe you should start by learning how to code simpler problems, you can't expect to hit the ground running. This isn't a place where anyone will help you learn how to code. To do that you'll need to read books, study, find a mentor, etc. If you can't understand the code you've pasted even enough to recognize if it's a function, a class, both, etc. then you are really out of your depth here and you should take a step back and learn the basics first. That's my advice.

Comment: @InBetween Working on that, thanks for the advice mate!.

Answer (score 1):

Given four points, **a**, **b**, **c**, and **d**, you can find the center by setting the following determinant to zero and solving it:

```
| (x^2  + y^2  + z^2)    x   y   z  1 |
| (ax^2 + ay^2 + az^2)  ax  ay  az  1 |
| (bx^2 + by^2 + bz^2)  bx  by  bz  1 | = 0.
| (cx^2 + cy^2 + cz^2)  cx  cy  cz  1 |
| (dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2)  dx  dy  dz  1 |
```

The math is gnarly, but the following C++ code implements the solution:

```cpp
class Point {
  public:
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
    Point() { x = 0; y = 0; z = 0; }
    Point(double x_, double y_, double z_) { x = x_; y = y_; z = z_; }
};
    
class Sphere {
  public:
    Point center;
    double radius;
    Sphere(Point center_, double radius_) {
        center = Point(center_.x, center_.y, center_.z);
        radius = radius_;
    }
};
    
Sphere
sphereFromFourPoints(Point a, Point b, Point c, Point d)
{
#define U(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) (a.z - b.z)*(c.x*d.y - d.x*c.y) - (e.z - f.z)*(g.x*h.y - h.x*g.y)
#define D(x,y,a,b,c) (a.x*(b.y-c.y) + b.x*(c.y-a.y) + c.x*(a.y-b.y))
#define E(x,y) ((ra*D(x,y,b,c,d) - rb*D(x,y,c,d,a) + rc*D(x,y,d,a,b) - rd*D(x,y,a,b,c)) / uvw)
    double u = U(a,b,c,d,b,c,d,a);
    double v = U(c,d,a,b,d,a,b,c);
    double w = U(a,c,d,b,b,d,a,c);
    double uvw = 2 * (u + v + w);
    if (uvw == 0.0) {
        // Oops.  The points are coplanar.
    }
    auto sq = [] (Point p) { return p.x*p.x + p.y*p.y + p.z*p.z; };
    double ra = sq(a);
    double rb = sq(b);
    double rc = sq(c);
    double rd = sq(d);
    double x0 = E(y,z);
    double y0 = E(z,x);
    double z0 = E(x,y);
    double radius = sqrt(sq(Point(a.x - x0, a.y - y0, a.z - z0)));
    return Sphere(Point(x0, y0, z0), radius);
#undef U
#undef D
#undef E
}
```

I wrote this code and I hereby place it in the public domain.  You do anything you want with it.

Comment: I've never seen #define used that way before, as a way to access elements of a struct or similar.  I'm not crazy about introducing U D and E into the preprocessor space tho.
Anyhow. Fantastic answer! I ported it to C# and it worked right off. Nice!

Comment: I added #undef's to clean up the preprocessor namespace.

Comment: Here it is as a fragment shader. https://www.shadertoy.com/view/7lXcW8. The #define approach compiled fine in GLSL.

Answer (score 1):

C# port of @Robert Bruce's excellent C++ answer. I don't claim to understand the math.  But I did add a test case and it worked !

```
using System;

/*
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70846528/230851

class Point {
  public:
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
    Point() { x = 0; y = 0; z = 0; }
    Point(double x_, double y_, double z_) { x = x_; y = y_; z = z_; }
};
    
class Sphere {
  public:
    Point center;
    double radius;
    Sphere(Point center_, double radius_) {
        center = Point(center_.x, center_.y, center_.z);
        radius = radius_;
    }
};
    
Sphere
sphereFromFourPoints(Point a, Point b, Point c, Point d)
{
#define U(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) (a.z - b.z)*(c.x*d.y - d.x*c.y) - (e.z - f.z)*(g.x*h.y - h.x*g.y)
#define D(x,y,a,b,c) (a.x*(b.y-c.y) + b.x*(c.y-a.y) + c.x*(a.y-b.y))
#define E(x,y) ((ra*D(x,y,b,c,d) - rb*D(x,y,c,d,a) + rc*D(x,y,d,a,b) - rd*D(x,y,a,b,c)) / uvw)
    double u = U(a,b,c,d,b,c,d,a);
    double v = U(c,d,a,b,d,a,b,c);
    double w = U(a,c,d,b,b,d,a,c);
    double uvw = 2 * (u + v + w);
    if (uvw == 0.0) {
        // Oops.  The points are coplanar.
    }
    auto sq = [] (Point p) { return p.x*p.x + p.y*p.y + p.z*p.z; };
    double ra = sq(a);
    double rb = sq(b);
    double rc = sq(c);
    double rd = sq(d);
    double x0 = E(y,z);
    double y0 = E(z,x);
    double z0 = E(x,y);
    double radius = sqrt(sq(Point(a.x - x0, a.y - y0, a.z - z0)));
    return Sphere(Point(x0, y0, z0), radius);
}

*/

static class SphereSolver
{
    public struct Point
    {
        public double x;
        public double y;
        public double z;

        public Point(double x, double y, double z)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.z = z;
        }

        public double component(int n)
        {
            switch (n)
            {
                case 0: return x;
                case 1: return y;
                case 2: return z;
                default: throw new Exception();
            }
        }
    };

    public struct Sphere
    {
        public Point center;
        public double radius;

        public Sphere(Point center, double radius)
        {
            this.center = center;
            this.radius = radius;
        }
    };

    public static Sphere SphereFromFourPoints(Point a, Point b, Point c, Point d)
    {
        static double U(Point a, Point b, Point c, Point d, Point e, Point f, Point g, Point h)
        {
            return (a.z - b.z) * (c.x * d.y - d.x * c.y) - (e.z - f.z) * (g.x * h.y - h.x * g.y);
        }
        static double D(int x, int y, Point a, Point b, Point c)
        {
            return a.component(x) * (b.component(y) - c.component(y)) +
                   b.component(x) * (c.component(y) - a.component(y)) +
                   c.component(x) * (a.component(y) - b.component(y));
        }

        static double E(int x, int y, Point a, Point b, Point c, Point d, double ra, double rb, double rc, double rd, double uvw)
        {
            return ( ra * D(x, y, b, c, d) - rb * D(x, y, c, d, a) +
                     rc * D(x, y, d, a, b) - rd * D(x, y, a, b, c) ) / uvw;
        }

        double u = U(a, b, c, d, b, c, d, a);
        double v = U(c, d, a, b, d, a, b, c);
        double w = U(a, c, d, b, b, d, a, c);
        double uvw = 2 * (u + v + w);
        if (uvw == 0.0)
        {
            // Oops.  The points are coplanar.
            // You probably want to replace this with abs(uvw) < epsilon, with some epsilon appropriate for your project.
        }

        static double sq(Point p)
        {
            return p.x * p.x + p.y * p.y + p.z * p.z;
        }

        int x = 0;
        int y = 1;
        int z = 2;
        double ra = sq(a);
        double rb = sq(b);
        double rc = sq(c);
        double rd = sq(d);
        double x0 = E(y, z, a, b, c, d, ra, rb, rc, rd, uvw);
        double y0 = E(z, x, a, b, c, d, ra, rb, rc, rd, uvw);
        double z0 = E(x, y, a, b, c, d, ra, rb, rc, rd, uvw);

        double radius = System.Math.Sqrt(sq(new Point(a.x - x0, a.y - y0, a.z - z0)));
        return new Sphere(new Point(x0, y0, z0), radius);
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SphereSolver.Sphere targetSphere = new SphereSolver.Sphere(new SphereSolver.Point(1, 2, 3), 5);

        SphereSolver.Point[] randomDirections =
        {
            new SphereSolver.Point(1, 1, 1),
            new SphereSolver.Point(7, 1, 5),
            new SphereSolver.Point(0, -4, -3),
            new SphereSolver.Point(-3, -5, -2),
        };

        SphereSolver.Point[] pointsOnTestSphere = new SphereSolver.Point[4];
        for (int n = 0; n < pointsOnTestSphere.Length; ++n)
        {
            SphereSolver.Point d = randomDirections[n];
            SphereSolver.Point p = new SphereSolver.Point();
            double length = Math.Sqrt(d.x * d.x + d.y * d.y + d.z * d.z);
            p.x = d.x * targetSphere.radius / length;
            p.y = d.y * targetSphere.radius / length;
            p.z = d.z * targetSphere.radius / length;
            p.x += targetSphere.center.x;
            p.y += targetSphere.center.y;
            p.z += targetSphere.center.z;
            pointsOnTestSphere[n] = p;
        }

        SphereSolver.Sphere answerSphere = SphereSolver.SphereFromFourPoints(
            pointsOnTestSphere[0],
            pointsOnTestSphere[1],
            pointsOnTestSphere[2],
            pointsOnTestSphere[3]
            );

        Console.WriteLine("Target Sphere: {0}, {1}, {2}, radius {3}", targetSphere.center.x, targetSphere.center.y, targetSphere.center.z, targetSphere.radius);
        Console.WriteLine("Answer Sphere: {0}, {1}, {2}, radius {3}", answerSphere.center.x, answerSphere.center.y, answerSphere.center.z, answerSphere.radius);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the first two points to define a line. Do the same with the second two. Find the POI between the two lines.

Comment: In three-dimensional space, the equidistant range between two points is a plane, not a line.

Comment: @EdwardPeters What are you talking about? In any dimensional space, two points have a well defined line between them...

Comment: The line **between** them is well-defined, but not useful. (There's no reason the center of the sphere would lay on that line, or that the two lines you describe would ever intersect.) Instead, you want to consider the set of points where are **equidistant** - because the point equidistant from the 4 input points will be the center of the sphere.

Comment: Suppose the sphere is Earth, and the points are the North Pole, the South Pole, New York and Boston. The line from the North Pole to the South pole does not intersect the line from New York to Boston. Additionally, if I took the corners of the square foundation of my house as the 4 points, then the lines between diagonal corners **would** intersect, but nowhere near the center. EDIT: Wrote this before you had a chance to edit. Leaving it here for posterity. :)

Comment: even in two dimensions, the intersection of two cords of a circle is not particularly useful and possibly doesn't even exist. (ie it may be outside the circle, but then you're not intersecting cords, just lines which pass through the circle)  However, if you take the perpendicular bisectors of each of those cords and find the intersection of the bisectors, that should be the center of a 2D circle.